# como chamar stored procedure com linq

Tags: c#, linq

Bom dia pessoal.
Tenho uma `stored procedure` no `sql server`,
e gostaria de chama-lo na minha aplicação `c#`,
via `linq`.
Desde ja agradeço qualquer ajuda

Answer (score 2):

Crie a Stored Procedure no seu banco de dados.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE BuscaCliente @nome varchar(255)          
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT * from Cliente where nome = @nome
END
```

- No Visual Studio adicione um arquivo do tipo LINQ to SQL, no meu caso
  vou adicionar com o nome Banco.dbml.
- Ao criar o arquivo, adicionei uma nova conexão em Server Explorer
  apontando para meu banco de dados de testes e navegue até a pasta
  StoredProcedures
- Clique e arraste a StoredProcedures para dentro do arquivo Banco.dbml
- Será adicionado um Método com o nome da SP, no código é só chamar a
  SP

O código abaixo mostra o uso da procedure:

```
BancoDataContext bd = new BancoDataContext();

var resultado = bd.BuscaCliente("celso");
foreach (var r in resultado){
  Console.Write(r.nome);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Fonte: http://csharpnamarra.blogspot.com.br/2013/04/linq-x-stored-procedure.html

Answer (score 2):

Boa tarde pessoal. ja resolvi o problema. pra quem tiver a mesma duvida ai vai a solução:

```
public List<SP_Comb> ListByCliente(int parametro1, string parametro2)
{
  List<SP_Comb> ListaCliente = new List<SP_Comb>();

  var q = DataContext.SP_ComboEntidade(parametro1, parametro2);

  foreach (var lista in q)
  {
    ListaCliente.Add(lista);
  }
  return ListaCliente;
}
```

onde:
`SP_Comb` - mapeamento das stored procedure(via sqlmetal)
`SP_ComboEntidade` - stored procedure